# python: select rows with two conditions

Tags: python

I am trying to select some rows of a data frame with two conditions.

```
a[a['col1']>=0 & a['col2']>=0,]
```

it gave me the error: **cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]**
Both columns with dtype are float64.
It seems that some examples online work for other people but I am not sure what was wrong with my situation.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add some parenthesis around the boolean masks:

```
a[(a['col1']>=0) & (a['col2']>=0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`&` has a higher precedence than `>=`.  Make sure to surround the conditions in parentheses.

```
a[(a['col1']>=0) & (a['col2']>=0),]
```

Comment: I tried but the comma caused me a problem. Many thanks for the comments!!!